# The 'crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled' attribute is not allowed

Tags: c#, json, wcf, cors

I have created a WCF service which receives data from the database of mySQL and shows as JSON data in the browser.

JSON data retrurned in the browser is as follows:

```
{"shipmentDetails":[{"Name":"AAA","Number":"123"},{"Name":"BBB","Number":"321"}]}
```

But I am unable to modify this service as cross domain access enabled,

The error comes here: web.config

```
<webHttpBinding>

<binding name="jsonpWebHttpBinding"  'crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"></binding>

</webHttpBinding>
```

I kindly request anyone to help me out why this attribute is not supported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? The first thing that comes to mind is that it is not supported in the version of the framework you are using right now. MSDN shows that it was introduced in .NET 4.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.crossdomainscriptaccessenabled(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I am using MS VS2010...

Comment: but what's the target framework in your project? Is it 3.5 or 4? right click on the project file and click properties...

Comment: thankyou @ Icarus it works.. previously I had 3.5.. now I changed it to 4.0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Adding the answer after OP confirmed that my comments pointed him in the right direction...)

The reason why the OP got the `The 'crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled' attribute is not allowed` error was because this attribute was first introduced in .NET 4.0 and the OP's project was targeting .NET 3.5. After changing the project to .NET 4.0, the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have symbol ' before attribute  crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled?

If you host your service on IIS, you can try this one:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"  />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET"  />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

It will give you more control over domain for accessing and methods for accessing.

You can also write your behavior to add proper headers to you messages: [Cross-domain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx)

Comment: Note: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * allows any domain which is a security risk